# TextView no wrapping special character Android

Tags: android, textview, word-wrap

Is there a way to create/override the custom word wrap engine for Android TextView?

For example,

**My name is Edwin (US:1113)**

Should be displayed as

**My name is Edwin**

**(US:1113)**

Instead of

**My name is Edwin (US:**

**1113)**

Already tried changing all the possible value for the setting below but nothing good.

```
Android:maxLines
Android:setHorizontallyScrolling
Android:ellipsize
Android:singleLine
```

In my findings, word wrap in TextView does not include special characters such as **:**.

**Updated 3.09AM 2/7/2018 UTC**

As mentioned by @Umair, line breaking with "\n" is not possible because I don't know the length of the text before the colon **:**. This will line break the sentence too early before it reached the maximum width of the TextView.

Comment: have you tried using `\n` ?

Comment: @Umair No because it should be done dynamically depending on the available width.

Comment: then use textview as match_parent and after that you can get the width of textview and put your text accordingly. Other then that every device will have it's own configuration so it will be alot difficult get the required result.

Comment: @Umair Yup, this is what I have done. But the problem I am facing is the colon " **:** " inside the text **(US:1113)**. Android TextView will split the text into **(US:** and **1113)** where they supposed to be considered as a single word.

Comment: one thing can be done, if you are sure the : will come everytime you display a value, then put a check if width is ending and : is there break the line or split the string, ?

Comment: @Umair Updated the question. Line breaking is not possible.

Comment: you can do it like I said you can get the width of textview if it's match_parent width and the text is : then break the line otherwise leave it as it is.

Comment: @Umair This is a good idea. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174149/discussion-between-edwin-and-umair).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use 2 TextViews inside a `LinearLayout` with `horizontal` orientation and put `My name is Edwin` in the 1st and `(US:1113)` in the 2nd. If there is no space for the 2nd TextView then it will fall to the next line.